# Extract zip and rar files in subdirectories

Tags: bash, ubuntu, extract

Using ubuntu, have never used bash script. Need to quickly extract all zip and rar files inside all my folders. The path where they should be extracted is the original location of the archive.

Comment: From command line: unzip files -d exdir

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -type f -iname "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
find / -type f -iname "*.rar" -exec unrar e {} \;
```

This 2 commands do exactly what you want, but I would change / to some more specific folder, for example /home/yourusername in order to prevent scanning of all directories.